# Laravel views do not output anything

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to PHP Laravel framework. I'm studying it and playing with simple examples of code. My problem is that my views do not output anything - a blank white screen appears when I try to reach controller methods, for example, localhost/my-application/cms/action1

My routes file:

```
Route::controller('cms', 'CmsController');
```

My controller:

```
class CmsController extends BaseController {

public function getIndex()
{
    View::make('cms.index');
}

public function getAction1()
{
    View::make('cms.action1');
}

public function getAction2()
{
    View::make('cms.action2');
}
```

}

My views are located in views/cms. They are very simple, for example:

```
<h1>Action1</h1>
<?php echo 'this is Action1'; ?>
```

And these views do not output anything, just simple blank white page appears. I tried to:

1) rename views files, and Laravel threw exception - "view not found", or so.

2) move view::make() methods to Routes file - the views were displayed then.

So where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The bootstrap index.php file in laravel is inside the public folder.</strike>

So unless you've created a vhost for your application, you have to access it like

localhost/my-application/public/cms/action1

**EDIT**

Forget it. The problem is that you do not return the view::make from each function.

```
return View::make('cms.index');
```

Comment: Sorry, we are talking about different problems. I can step into my getAction1() method with debugger. I even can echo something in that method. But the views do not output anything.